# Windows 7 PC refusing connection from Windows XP PC. System Error 67

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-xp, file-sharing

So I have several PC's on a small local network.

Server - Windows 8 Professional

Client 1 - Windows 8.1
Client 2 - Windows 8.1
Client 3 - Windows 7 professional
Client 4 - Windows XP professional.

All of the client PC's need to access a network share on the "server". I'm also using SyncToy for automation. The only one that has a problem is the XP machine which after a while will no longer connect to the server. If use "NET USE \\SERVER" I get "system error 67". If I "PING \\SERVER" it resolves the IP Addr, but all of the packets fail. If I reboot the XP client, the same thing happens, however if I reboot the SERVER, everything is working fine again until some later time when it stops working again. It seems the server is the one causing the problem, but with only one specific computer.

Any idea where to begin diagnosing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This could be an IP-conflict. - Maybe some of your devices (printers etc.) are using fixed IP-adress. This might cause two devices to use the same IP. In that case, the latest connected or the one with automatic IP is blocked by the router/switch. - Make sure, you are using **either** auto IP on all devices (preferable), .. **or** fixed IP on all devices.